# Stylesheets in external SVG - are they loaded from cache or twice?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following code to export an external SVG image (I can't use it inline for a number of reasons):

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css">
</head>

...

<object data="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

The image itself:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="theme.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">...</svg>
```

So for the image I am loading the same `theme.css` I am loading for the page to use some classes from it. It works fine, however I wonder if the page loading speed is affected by that? I checked the console and it looks like the second `theme.css` is loaded 10x times faster. Anybody can clarify how it works?

Comment: Depends on the browser and the version of that browser I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your browsers developer tools by pressing F12, view the Network tab, and then reload the page you can see whether a resource was loaded from memory cache or disk cache.

You can also test doing a refresh by using Shift+F5 for a refresh without cache to see if the speeds slow down again.